# Checksum using Gradle: MD5 for a tar and zip file

Tags: gradle, hash, md5, md5sum

Before unpacking a tar and a zip file I want to calculate the md5sum of that files to check if the files are the right files.

Comment: Which task do you use for unpacking a tar or zip?

Comment: zipTree() and tarTree()